# Find the coordinate of center point on an edge of OSMNX

Tags: edges, osmnx

I am looking to find the coordinates (Lat, Lon) of a center point on any edge of a network of OSMNX.

For instance my network is:

```
G=ox.graph_from_place('San Diego County, CA', network_type='drive')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `interpolate` function from shapely.

```
import osmnx as ox
G=ox.graph_from_place('San Diego', network_type='drive')
nodes, edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=True, edges=True)
```

Derive midpoint for every edge of the graph.

```
edges['midpoint'] = ''
for i in range(0,len(edges)):
    midpoint = edges['geometry'].iloc[i].interpolate(0.5, normalized = True)
    edges['midpoint'].iloc[i] = midpoint
```

Plot the graph. Nodes are denoted by red. Midpoints of edges are denoted by green.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, node_size=2, figsize=(48, 48),node_color='r', show=False, close=False)    
for i in range(0,len(edges)):
    ax.scatter(edges['midpoint'].iloc[i].x, edges['midpoint'].iloc[i].y, c='g', s = 2)    
plt.show()
```

Output (cropped image shown):
[image]